# How do I use Google cloud storage for my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-cloud-platform, cloud-storage

I have a rails app created with rails 6.0. I've been trying to deploy my app to heroku. However, heroku is giving the error: > heroku logs --tail

I think this is happening because I'm not using any cloud storage to store my images. I've searched on the internet how to do it with amazon s3, google cloud. But for all of them I was asked to give my requisites for later payment. Is it possible to use any cloud storage without showing personal payment details as I don't have any cards to pay right now, and PayPal also doesn't function in my country.

Comment: You can check this for configuration [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#google-cloud-storage-service), on Heroku you can use ENV variables instead of Rails credentials.

Comment: Also check this https://pjbelo.medium.com/setting-up-rails-5-2-active-storage-using-google-cloud-storage-and-heroku-23df91e830f8

Answer (score 0):

When using the Google Cloud Platform (commonly known as “GCP”), **each of your applications requires a project**, and **each project requires an active billing account**. The [payment methods available](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods) for the Cloud Billing accounts depend on your [currency & country](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency). In many countries, you can set up a credit card, debit card, or bank account as a primary payment method. So, as you can see credit card is required to use GCP services.

If you want just check if Google Cloud Storage suits your needs you can create a [free GCP tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) account, but it will still need your payment details.

Same situation with **AWS** - [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/free-tier-payment-method/) also requires you to provide credit card info.

You can also search the Internet for a service that will provide a virtual debit card or a remote bank account.